# Count the number of times money was withdrawn from bank account

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make it so that it counts how many withdrawals a user can have before the bank account's balance is below 0. The inputted numbers are 1000, 60, 50, 300, 800, 53, 2009, and 2015. It's supposed to start with 1000 and subtract 60, then 50, then 300, then 800, which would be 4 withdrawals. Mine doesn't do that and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
Private Sub btnBankAccount_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBankAccount.Click
    Dim inFile As StreamReader = New StreamReader("bank1.txt")
    Dim withdrawls As Integer 'count times
    Dim money As Integer 'amount of money
    Dim difference As Integer = 0 'difference caused by the withdrawls


    Do 'read in numbers
        money = Val(inFile.ReadLine())
        'determine the amount of money
        If money > 0 Then
            withdrawls = withdrawls + 1
            difference = difference - money
        End If
    Loop Until difference < 0
    'display results
    Me.lblOutput.Text = withdrawls
End Sub
```

Comment: `difference` is starting at zero so the first withdrawal will send it below zero. Don't you want it starting at `1000`?

Comment: Yea, I figured that, but how do I make it count the withdrawals? I've also tried making a balance and subtracting from it but that didn't work. I just don't know how to make the inputted numbers go to the right variables to make it work.

Comment: It seems to me it should work with `1000` as the starting `difference`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your code should work if you defined `difference` as this:

```
Dim difference As Integer = 0
```

Now, just to help you with coding style, I'd suggest you write your code like this:

```
Private Sub btnBankAccount_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBankAccount.Click
    Me.lblOutput.Text = GetWithdrawlCount(1000, "bank1.txt")
End Sub

Private Function GetWithdrawlCount(ByVal limit As Decimal, ByVal file As String) As Integer

    Dim withdrawls As Integer = 0
    Dim difference As Decimal = limit

    For Each line In System.IO.File.ReadLines(file)
        Dim money = Decimal.Parse(line)
        If money > 0 Then
            withdrawls = withdrawls + 1
            difference = difference - money
        End If
        If difference < 0 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Return withdrawls

End Function
```

I've purposely separated out `GetWithdrawlCount` so that there are **no references to any UI element** and that there are no **magic numbers** or **magic strings** in the code. Writing it this way makes your code cleaner and easier to test.